# VBA: Conditional formatting cell colors based of timer with it's own conditions

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements

I have a timer in a text box that will change from green, to yellow, and to red as the timer counts up. The time intervals at which the color changes is determined by the selection from a drop down in a cell.

Question: How can I get surrounding cells to also change color??

```
    If StopWatch.Range("E3") = "Anodized" Then
    
        If Calculations.Range("A1").Value > Calculations.Range("B3") And _
           Calculations.Range("A1").Value <= Calculations.Range("B4") Then
            With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox")
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0) 'Green
            End With
        Else
            If Calculations.Range("A1").Value > Calculations.Range("B4") And _
               Calculations.Range("A1").Value <= Calculations.Range("B5") Then

                With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox")
                    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0) 'Yelow
                End With
            
            Else
                If Calculations.Range("A1").Value > Calculations.Range("B5") Then
                    With StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox")
                        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Red
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

The above code is a sample of the conditional formatting that I have at the moment. I have this repeated for several other options in the drop down box.

Comment: If you know the range you want to color then `myRange.Interior.Color = vbRed` (for example) should work fine.

Comment: Reference the surrounding cells using `StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox").TopLeftCell.Offset(ROWS,COLUMNS).Resize(ROWS,COLUMNS)`. For example if I wanted every adjacent cell around TimeBox I could reference them like `StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox").TopLeftCell.Offset(-1,-1).Resize(3,3)` which would return a 3x3 Range around the TimeBox's top left corner

Comment: Toddleson 
Using your method to reference a group of cells, how do I tie their interior color to the interior color of the shape "TimeBox"

Answer (score 1):

Expanding my comment into a full answer...

Reference the surrounding cells using `StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox").TopLeftCell.Offset(ROWS,COLUMNS).Resize(ROWS,COLUMNS)`. For example if I wanted every adjacent cell around TimeBox I could reference them like `StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox").TopLeftCell.Offset(-1,-1).Resize(3,3)` which would return a 3x3 Range around the TimeBox's top left corner.

Here is your code with this applied. I also changed your If/Else into a much cleaner looking Select Case.

```vb
    Dim LowerLimit As Variant, MidLimit As Variant, UpperLimit As Variant
    LowerLimit = Calculations.Range("B3").Value
    MidLimit = Calculations.Range("B4").Value
    UpperLimit = Calculations.Range("B5").Value
    
    Dim TimeBox As Shape, SurroundingRange As Range
    Set TimeBox = StopWatch.Shapes("TimeBox")
    Set SurroundingRange = TimeBox.TopLeftCell.Offset(-1, -1).Resize(3, 3) 'Edit this range as neccesary
    
    If StopWatch.Range("E3") = "Anodized" Then
        Select Case Calculations.Range("A1").Value
        Case LowerLimit To MidLimit
            TimeBox.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0) 'Green
            SurroundingRange.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        Case MidLimit To UpperLimit
            TimeBox.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0) 'Yellow
            SurroundingRange.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        Case Is > UpperLimit
            TimeBox.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'Red
            SurroundingRange.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End Select
    End If
```